# DPDK Crypto device not found

Tags: drivers

I am trying to add crypto devices especaially cryptodev_qat in order to run some test. I am follwing the given links but not working properly, everything seems working fine.

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/videos/dpdk-crypto-get-started-with-intel-quickassist-technology.html

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/cryptodevs/qat.html#binding-the-available-vfs-to-the-vfio-pci-driver

Looking for something better to find the issue. Becuase its doesnt show any error.

Comment: Welcome! Please **edit** you question and tell us what Ubuntu version and type you are using, and generally more information about your system and issues you're trying to resolve so we can help you better.

Comment: @SohailAnjum can you please update the error you are facing? also please update with the following details `1) DPDK version, 2) sample application is from DPDK examples or not? 3) what is the exact cmdline used, 4) result of lspci | grep -i qat, 5) lsmod | grep -i qat, 6) dpdk-devbind.py -s, 7) running the application with --log-level=pmd,8`, These will give correct information to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Thanks I had solved this issue.